# pandas assign columns values depend on another column in the df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df`,

```
id    a_id    b_id
1     25      50
1     25      50
2     26      51
2     26      51
3     25      52
3     28      52
3     28      52
```

I have the following code to assign `a_id` and `b_id` to `-1`, based on how many rows each of them has for each `id` value in the `df`; if each of `a_id` or `b_id` value has exactly the same rows/sub-df as a specific value of `id` has, those rows of `a_id` and `b_id` get -1;

```
cluster_ids = df.loc[df['id'] > -1]['id'].unique()

types = ['a_id', 'b_id']

for cluster_id in cluster_ids:
    rows = df.loc[df['id'] == cluster_id]

    for type in types:
        ids = rows[type].values

        match_rows = df.loc[df[type] == ids[0]]

        if match_rows.equals(rows):
           df.loc[match_rows.index, type] = -1
```

so the result df will look like,

```
id    a_id    b_id
1     25      -1
1     25      -1
2     -1      -1
2     -1      -1
3     25      -1
3     28      -1
3     28      -1
```

I am wondering if there a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Your explanation is not clear. Would you mind clarifying what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: @coldspeed has modified the op;

Comment: Is there any scenario where it cant be -1? We need a different example for making it clear.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't get it. Everything is -1 here, so I can't visualise any false cases.

Comment: @coldspeed, Dark  have modified the example in the op, sry for the unclearness

Comment: code you've provided actually creates a different output than the one you have provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
one_value_for_each_id = df.groupby('id').transform(lambda x: len(set(x)) == 1)

 a_id  b_id
0   True  True
1   True  True
2   True  True
3   True  True
4  False  True
5  False  True
6  False  True

one_id_for_each_value = pd.DataFrame({
    col: df.groupby(col).id.transform(lambda x: len(set(x)) == 1)
    for col in ['a_id', 'b_id']
})

   a_id  b_id
0  False  True
1  False  True
2   True  True
3   True  True
4  False  True
5   True  True
6   True  True

one_to_one_relationship = one_id_for_each_value & one_value_for_each_id

# Set all values that satisfy the one-to-one relationship to `-1`
df.loc[one_to_one_relationship.a_id, 'a_id'] = -1
df.loc[one_to_one_relationship.b_id, 'b_id'] = -1

a_id  b_id
0    25    -1
1    25    -1
2    -1    -1
3    -1    -1
4    25    -1
5    28    -1
6    28    -1
```